# Rails Server command returns CL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to follow Michael Hartl's rails tutorial, but whenever I issue the rails server command the following error returns. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Justin\Documents\rails_projects\first_app>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb:81:
in `parse': Illformed requirement ["2.0.0."] (ArgumentError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requi
rement.rb:106:in `block in initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requi
rement.rb:106:in `map!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requi
rement.rb:106:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requi
rement.rb:44:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requi
rement.rb:44:in `create'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/depen
dency.rb:50:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dependency.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:58:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:58:in `gem'
        from C:/Users/Justin/Documents/rails_projects/first_app/Gemfile:25:in `e
valuate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
```

Comment: You probably have illformed gem version in Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill formed gemfile was correct, added an extra . after a version "2.0.0."